# GDB Debugger Error

Tags: linux, gcc, gdb

I am very sorry, if my English is bad. This problem is getting me for days.
I have a simple C source code with a sub function which I am examining. First I am creating the .out file with gcc. This file I am examining with GDB. But if I want to disassemble the called function I always get an error message from gdb.
Prolog:

```
unix@unix-laptop:~/booksrc $ gcc -g stack_example.c
unix@unix-laptop:~/booksrc $ gdb -q ./a.out
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libthread_db.so.1".
(gdb) disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x08048357 <main+0>:    push   %ebp
0x08048358 <main+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
0x0804835a <main+3>:    sub    $0x18,%esp
0x0804835d <main+6>:    and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
0x08048360 <main+9>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
0x08048365 <main+14>:   sub    %eax,%esp
0x08048367 <main+16>:   movl   $0x4,0xc(%esp)
0x0804836f <main+24>:   movl   $0x3,0x8(%esp)
0x08048377 <main+32>:   movl   $0x2,0x4(%esp)
0x0804837f <main+40>:   movl   $0x1,(%esp)
0x08048386 <main+47>:   call   0x8048344 <test_function>
0x0804838b <main+52>:   leave  
0x0804838c <main+53>:   ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) disass test_function()
You can't do that without a process to debug.
(gdb)
```

Do you have an idea for the reason of the error? I have already used google but I can't find anything to solve the problem. I also searched for the instructions to be sure that the syntax is right.
http://visualgdb.com/gdbreference/commands/disassemble

Thanks for reading,
Intersect!

Comment: How do you compile your C code ; show the exact command (it should start with `gcc -Wall -g`). How do you run `gdb`? Which versions of `gcc` and of `gdb` are you using?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the typed command in place (not as screenshots on some external site). Start each command with at least four spaces in a separate paragraph.

Comment: Please put the TEXT of the error messages here! Putting an image to an external site is not welcome.

Comment: Done. I read the comments yet. In future i will post always the error message.. it was easier, because i am working in a virtualbox...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax (of the `gdb` [command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Commands.html#Commands)) is `disass` *function-name* so you should type

```
 disass test_function
```

Read the genuine [GDB documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/).

But you typed wrongly <strike>`disass test_function()`</strike> ;  then ending parenthesis are wrong.

Be sure that you compiled your source code with `gcc -Wall -g`

At last, you could ask `gcc` to output an assembler file. Try for instance to compile your `source.c` file with

```
gcc -O1 -S -fverbose-asm source.c
```

<sup>(you could omit the `-O1` or replace it with `-g` if you wanted to)</sup>

then look with an editor (or some pager) into the generated `source.s` assembly file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the function isn't there because it was inlined during compilation. I had never seen your error message before, sorry.

Please try to compile with the following additional flags:

```
-O0 -g
```

You can also see all function start addresses with:

```
objdump -x <filename>
```

This gives you a list of symbols in your executable file which includes all the start points of functions.

You can also disassemble your code with:

```
objdump -d <filename>
```